# Extract template variadic arguments types of a templated function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a Vertex struct defined with a variadic template and I would like to have a templated function somewhere else that would use a fold expression to "iterate" over the Vertex's type parameters:

```cpp
template <typename ... VTs>
struct Vertex;

template<template<typename ... VTs> typename V>
void bindAttributes() const {
    // I'll add some assertion V == Vertex
    uint32_t i, offset = 0;
    (addAttrib<VTs>(i++, sizeof(Vertex<VTs ...>), offset), ...);
}
```

I get a `VTs was not declared in this scope` when compiling this and the following error if I comment line `(addAttrib<VTs>(i++, sizeof(Vertex<VTs ...>), offset), ...);`

```
/foo/Terrain.cpp:145:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘OGLR::VertexArray::bindAttributes<OGLR::TerrainVertex>()’
  145 |         tb.va.bindAttributes<TerrainVertex>();
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from /foo/blah.h: note: candidate: ‘template<template<class ... VTs> class V> void OGLR::VertexArray::bindAttributes() const’
   30 |         void bindAttributes() const {
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/foo/blahblah.h:30:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/foo/Terrain.cpp:145:44: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<template<class ... VTs> class V> void OGLR::VertexArray::bindAttributes() const’
  145 |         tb.va.bindAttributes<TerrainVertex>();
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/foo/Terrain.cpp:145:44: note:   expected a class template, got ‘OGLR::TerrainVertex’ {aka ‘OGLR::Vertex<glm::vec<2, float, glm::packed_highp>, glm::vec<3, float, glm::packed_highp> >’}
```

However, I'm strugling to write the second template definition since I can't manage to extract the "inner types" VTs.

The idea would be for this to work:

```cpp
typedef Vertex<glm::vec2, glm::vec3> TerrainVertex;

...

addAtributes<TerrainVertex>();
```

I saw multiple times code mentioned online with

```cpp
template<template<typename ...> typename Foo>
```

but there I can't extract the template's types...

Thanks for the help!

**Edit:**
Here is a minimal reproducible example

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename ... Attrib>
struct Vertex {};

template<template <typename ... Attrib> typename V>
void bindAttrib() {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Vertex<Attrib ...>, V<Attrib...>>, "Unwanted type");
    (std::cout << "Size of one attrib is: " << sizeof(Attrib), ...);
}

int main() {
    typedef Vertex<uint32_t, float, char> TerrainVertex;
    bindAttrib<TerrainVertex>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mre]. It'd be nice to have a minimal example that we can copy-paste and get the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

`template<template<typename ... VTs> typename V> void bindAttributes() const`
is equivalent to
`template<template<typename ...> typename V> void bindAttributes() const`.

What you want is
`template<typename T> void bindAttributes() const` and extract information from `T`:

```
template<typename T> void bindAttributes() const
{
    [this]<typename...Ts>(std::type_identity<Vertex<Ts...>>){
        uint32_t i = 0;
        uint32_t offset = 0;
        (this->addAttrib<Ts>(i++, sizeof(Vertex<Ts ...>), offset), ...);
    }(std::type_identity<T>());
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the idea, tried it out quickly and it compiled but didn't seem to work, I'm not quite sure how `type_identity` works but I get the gist of it, I'll have to check on my `addAttrib` to make sure that's not the problem

Comment: It won't let me edit so I'll say it here, I made it work and I suppose it was either the uninitialised `i` or the absence of `this->addAttrib`. But in any case it's all good!

Comment: Uninitialised `i` is indeed problematic leading to UB, (I copied paste that part without checking :-/ ). `this->` would be needed if `addAttrib` comes from template base class.